# Set current directory - apple script

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an application and a `.sh` file. I need an apple script that when double clicked, sets the permission of that `.sh` file and runs it.
Below is my code:

```
set app_directory to POSIX path of ((container of (path to me)) as text)

tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "chmod 777 " & app_directory & " start.sh"
tell application "Terminal" to do shell script app_direcory & "start.sh"
```

But I get following error:

> error "Can’t make container of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:santhosh:Desktop:EPPFN ver1:Barcode Application_mac:test_app.app:\" into type text." number -1700 from container of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:santhosh:Desktop:EPPFN ver1:Barcode Application_mac:test_app.app:" to text

How do I set the current path and then use the relative path to run the script.

EDIT:
I modified the code to:

```
set x to POSIX file ((POSIX path of (path to me)) & "/..") as text
set thescript to ("chmod 777 " & x & "start.sh") as text
tell application "Terminal" to do shell script (thescript)
```

still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to set app_directory to POSIX path of (container of (path to me))
set thescript to ("chmod 777 " & quoted form of (app_directory & "/start.sh"))
do shell script thescript
```